# How do I retrieve the number of distinct rows with the JPA Criteria API

Tags: java, jpa, criteria-api

I need to count the number of rows returned by a `CriteriaQuery`. The relevant piece of information here is that those need to be distinct rows based on a dynamically selected set of **columns**.

This means, that I cannot count over the entire table, since that might consider results, that would be redundant if you strip a certain number of columns.

I have a List of Predicates and Selections to conform to:

```
 private final List<Selection<?>> projection = new ArrayList<>();
 private final List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
```

and I want to count the number of rows that would be returned, if this query was executed non-paginated:

```
criteriaQuery.multiselect(projection)
        .distinct(true)
        .where(cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0])));
```

The usual approach of transforming this into a `Subquery` will not work, since you cant `multiselect` on a `Subquery` and also can't select from the `Subquery`.

Can this be done with the Criteria API?

Answer (score 0):

can you try this ?

CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery query = builder.createQuery(String.class);

Root ruleVariableRoot = query.from(RuleVar.class);
query.select(ruleVariableRoot.get(RuleVar_.varType)).distinct(true);

More infos: https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/criteria

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to comment on this issue; sadly this does not solve the question as I need to select multiple entries and get the corresponding count, and I do not see how this will do it.